# How to not display this blue frame around my image?

Tags: html, css

I've got an image that is a link to a pop-up calendar where the display renders a blue frame around my image since I made it a link to make the cursor change to a hand when hovered:
[image]

where HTML is

```
<div class="fl20">Depositionsdatum:</div>
<div class="fl40"><input type="text" size="10" name="depositionsdatum"
      id="depositionsdatum" value="">&nbsp;<a href="#"><img src="images/cal.gif" width="16"
      height="15" alt="" onclick="javascript:openCalWin('620','300','depositionsdatum')"></a></div>
```

The CSS is

```
 .avnamn {
color:arial #90002b;
font-size:140%;
display:inline;
vertical-align:3%;
margin-left:1%;
}

.b {
border:1px solid #000;
}

.Webdings {
font-family:Webdings;
}

ul {
margin-top:0;
}

.mt3 {
margin-top:-3px;
}

.mt5p {
margin-top:5px;
}

.fontS80 {
font-size:80%;
}

.link {
color:#036;
text-decoration:underline;
cursor:pointer;
font-weight:700;
}

.link_sm {
color:#036;
text-decoration:underline;
font-size:70%;
cursor:pointer;
}

.smallg {
font-size:75%;
color:#555;
}

.ssmall {
font-size:65%;
font-weight:700;
color:#555;
}

.small60 {
font-size:60%;
}

.small50 {
font-size:50%;
color:#333;
}

.smallb {
font-size:85%;
}

table {
display:inline;
}

h1 {
font-size:130%;
display:inline;
}

h2 {
font-size:100%;
display:inline;
}

h4 {
font-size:70%;
display:inline;
}

.hthin {
font-size:125%;
}

.th {
text-align:left;
}

td,th {
font-size:75%;
vertical-align:text-top;
}

.td_link {
cursor:pointer;
}

.td40 {
height:40px;
}

.td60 {
height:60px;
}

.thkant {
border-top:1px solid #000;
border-bottom:1px solid #000;
font-size:70%;
text-align:left;
}

.bb {
border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}

.bbV {
border-bottom:1px solid #FFF;
}

.TB_bt,.TB_nb,.TB_db,.TB_bb {
background-color:#efefdc;
}

.hk {
background-color:#d9ddb3;
}

.hknot {
background-color:#f9faf2;
}

.TB_bt {
border-top:1px solid #FFF;
}

.TB_bt5 {
border-top:5px solid #FFF;
}

.TB_bb {
border-bottom:1px solid #999;
}

.TB_bb2 {
border-bottom:2px solid #c1c1b3;
}

.TB_db {
border-bottom:1px solid #000;
border-top:1px solid #000;
}

.TB_tb {
border-top:2px solid #efefdc;
}

.TB_bo_hk {
border-top:1px solid #efefdc;
}

.TB_bo2 {
border:1px solid #efefdc;
}

.TB_bo2B {
border-top:2px solid #c1c1b3;
border-left:3px solid #efefdc;
border-right:3px solid #efefdc;
border-bottom:2px solid #c1c1b3;
}

.TD_bo {
border-right:1px solid #c1c1b3;
width:9%;
font-size:70%;
text-align:center;
}

.TD_bo2 {
border-right:0;
width:9%;
font-size:70%;
text-align:center;
}

.ytb {
border-left:3px solid #efefdc;
border-right:3px solid #efefdc;
}

.datum {
font-size:70%;
padding-right:5px;
vertical-align:text-top;
}

.sub {
background:#EAEAEA;
}

.sub_meny,.sub_meny_r,.sub_meny_active,.sub_meny_sm {
font-size:70%;
padding-left:20px;
padding-right:20px;
vertical-align:text-top;
}

.sub_meny_sm {
font-size:60%;
vertical-align:middle;
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px;
}

.sub_meny_r {
float:right;
font-size:70%;
padding-left:8px;
padding-right:8px;
}

.sub_meny_rm {
margin-top:4px;
}

.sub_meny_active {
font-weight:700;
}

.flikkant1 {
background-image:url(../images/fl1k.jpg);
background-position:center;
z-index:-1;
}

.inl_namn {
font-weight:700;
font-size:70%;
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
}

.tr {
text-align:right;
}

.g1 {
background-color:#FFF;
line-height:20px;
}

.g2 {
background-color:#EEE;
line-height:20px;
}

.g3 {
background-color:#DCDCDC;
line-height:20px;
font-weight:700;
font-size:100%;
}

.g4 {
background-color:#CCC;
line-height:20px;
}

.popup {
background-color:#FFF;
font-size:70%;
border-color:#000;
border-style:groove;
border-width:2px;
padding:0;
}

.popupN {
background-color:#F0F0E3;
color:#000;
width:100%;
display:inline;
font-weight:700;
height:auto;
border-bottom:1px solid #000;
padding:2px;
}

.pin {
padding:6px;
}

.fl10,.fl20,.fl30,.fl40,.fl50,.fl60,.fl70,.fl80,.fl90,.fl100 {
padding-bottom:4px;
color:#000;
}

.over {
background-color:#EFEFDC;
line-height:20px;
}

.half {
line-height:50%;
}

.quarter {
line-height:25%;
}

.lh10 {
line-height:10%;
}

.checkmargin {
margin-right:25px;
}

.checkmarginL {
margin-left:25px;
}

.pusher {
padding-left:15px;
}

.pusherR {
margin-right:40px;
}

.rand3 {
background-color:#FFF;
line-height:3px;
}

.rand1 {
background-color:#FFF;
line-height:1px;
}

.whiteborder {
color:#fff;
border:4px solid #fff;
margin:10px;
padding:10px;
}

#details {
width:580px;
color:#fff;
}

.column1 {
color:#000;
width:500px;
border:0;
float:left;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.column2 {
color:#000;
border:0;
width:80px;
float:right;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.f200 {
color:#000;
}

.f210 {
color:#000;
float:left;
}

.inp_sel {
width:80%;
}

.form-bg {
background:#eeefdf;
width:1080px;
overflow:hidden;
}

.data-bar {
border-bottom:1px solid #fbfbf7;
display:inline-block;
padding:10px;
}

.left {
float:left;
width:200px;
}

.right {
float:right;
width:700px;
}

.data-box {
width:650px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid #cbcbcb;
}

#table td {
margin:120px;
}

.personName {
float:left;
width:300px;
}

.otherDetails {
float:right;
width:300px;
}

.readonly,.TB_nbA {
background-color:#CCC;
}

a:link,a:visited,a:hover,a:active {
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
}

.fontS75,.small {
font-size:75%;
}

h3,h5 {
font-size:80%;
display:inline;
font-family:"Arial Unicode MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.TB_bo,.b2 {
border:2px solid #efefdc;
}
```

I want the image to render like it does an another place on the same page:
[image]
Here it has no blue frame and the code is nearly identical:

```
<div id="datum" class="fl20">Datum ingivningsdag:</div>
        <div class="fl20"><input type="text" name="ingivningsdag" 
    id="ingivningsdag" value="2012-04-11">&nbsp;<a href="#"><img src="images/cal.gif" alt="" width="16" height="15" border="0" onclick="javascript:openCalWin('620','300','ingivningsdag')"></a></div>
```

Why does it work on one place and not the other?

Comment: Chrome's developer tools (and probably others as well) would immediately show you that the element has a border (in the CSS sense of the word) and tell you where the value for that border comes from. Try them out.

Comment: your code is not identical. Missing the `border=0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have matched both code before asking, answer was in front of you. ;)

in first code there is no border="0"

and in second code there is a border="0"

Apply this css

```
  a img
    {
        border: 0;
        outline:0;(for removing dotted borders  from image and links.You gonna need this in future )
    }
```

or apply border="0" on first code.

Comment: Thank you. Now it looks much better.

Comment: I wouldn't append outline: 0 due to accessibility reasons. Means it would remove the outline when you focuse the element.

Comment: @NickRosencrantz you can select any of answer so this thread can be closed

Comment: @JannisM I agree with you but there are other way for focus, I always hear this from most of the client they say, they dont want to see any dotted border around there image and there link, and trust me they really look annoying that's why I added this

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot that this was answered so quickly.

Answer (score 4):

The code isn't identical.

Note that the 2nd instance has `border="0"` set.  You either need to set it as an attribute on the IMG element or (preferred), use a CSS selector to set `border:none`.

Answer (score 3):

Simply set `border=0` on the image, either in the HTML like so:

```
<img src="images/cal.gif" width="16" height="15" alt="" border="0" onclick="javascript:openCalWin('620','300','depositionsdatum')"></a>`
```

or CSS:

```
a img
{
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This would do it:

```
a img {
   border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the image wrapped in an anchor so it's the link which has the border.

```
a img { border:none; }
```

Comment: and why are you targetting anyway the anchor?

Comment: @JannisM i think you didn't noticed HTML from Question, img is wrapped around anchor tag that's why he used anchor.

Comment: Agreee, but border: 0 to <img /> tag should be always there

Answer (score 1):

`<img />` has a default border of 1px. Set `border: 0;` in your Stylesheet or use `border="0"` inline within you `<img />` tag.

Answer (score 1):

use this css-

```
a img {border:none;outline:0;}
```

also you can use it if you need-

```
a:hover, a:active, a:focus {outline:0;}
```